# Quartz.Net error on common logging.

Tags: quartz.net

I am getting the following error:

```
2013-11-14 11:57:33,994 [TestScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] ERROR Common.Loggi
ng.Factory.AbstractLogger.Error(:0) - An error occurred while scanning for the n
ext trigger to fire.
Quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't acquire next trigger: Cannot insert the
    value NULL into column 'SCHED_TIME', table 'quartz.dbo.QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS'; co
lumn does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cann
ot insert the value NULL into column 'SCHED_TIME', table 'quartz.dbo.QRTZ_FIRED_
TRIGGERS'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I am using the example from [HERE](https://github.com/jvilalta/QuartzNetTutorial) and I think I need to understand how jobs work with ADO.Net Jobstore better. My code works perfectly with RAMJobStore. Is there something else I have to do to get ADO to scan for triggers?

Comment: What version version of Quartz.NET are you running? The column was added later on and support for comes with library version 2.2 and later.

Comment: Yes I am using 2.2. When I turn set useProperties = "true" I get new error: {"Couldn't store trigger 'njobTriggerGroup.njobTrigger' for 'njobGroup.njob' job: Unable to cast object of type 'Quartz.JobDataMap' to type 'System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection'."}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out when I looked closer at the errors it was referencing the older version of Quartz.net.